# why does Twilio work in Egypt and doesn't work in India?

Tags: django, twilio

I'm working on the project and doing some integration with OPT Twilio by phone verification.

now I should type the code of the country I work in to receive the correct phone number so, in Egypt when I type:

+20...

it works for me and I succeeded in log into my page but when I use the Indian code key which is: +91 it doesn't work

I don't have any idea where is the problem located in!

also, I searched for the countries that Twilio work with then, I noticed that page:
https://www.visitnorthwest.com/country-codes/91-country-code/
that refers to Twilio can work with India

so, any hint or help, please

thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to illustrate what you are trying to do. Then describe what the results are and what you want it to do instead. See [ask] for tips on improving your question so we can help.

Comment: I already did that, I gave an example such as: when I typed +20 in case of the code key was by Egypt it works, but if it was by India code key such as:+91 it doesn't work. what I'm trying to do is that I want to know how can I fix this problem. is there anything not understandable in my question?

Comment: This is not really a question for Stack Overflow. If you are having issues with delivering messages in India I would contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact).

Comment: Does your question fit the guidelines given in [help/on-topic]?